# Calling an API from CronJob in Node gives no response

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, slack-api

I am attempting to call the slackbot API from within a CronJob, I want a message to be sent to the channel at a certain time during the day but the method in question does not work when called from within the CronJob. The following is the relevant code:

```
Shiftbot.prototype.run = function () {
    Shiftbot.super_.call(this, this.settings);

    this.on('start', this._onStart);
    this.on('message', this._onMessage);
};

Shiftbot.prototype._onStart = function() {
    this._loadBotUser();
    new CronJob('* * 16 * * *', function(){
        console.log('You will see this message every second ');
        Shiftbot.prototype._sendReminder();
    }, null, true, "America/New_York");
}

Shiftbot.prototype._sendReminder = function() { 
    console.log('test');
    this.postMessageToChannel("shiftbot_beta", "Cron test", {as_user: true});
}
```

The `_sendReminder` method above works fine when it is called from another `Shiftbot.prototype.*` method but not from within the cronjob. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created the variable `self` in the scope of Shiftbot.prototype and used it within the scope of the `CronJob` as follows:

```
Shiftbot.prototype._onStart = function() {
    var self = this;
    this._loadBotUser();
    new CronJob('* * 16 * * *', function(){
        console.log('You will see this message every second ');
        self._sendReminder();
    }, null, true, "America/New_York");
}
```